# Is there a Google sheets or Apps Script function for converting numbered coordinates into numbered and lettered grid references?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, coordinates

I need to convert columns of numbered coordinates into a different unit of measurement. From WGS84 Latitude/Longitude to OSGB36 Grid Reference.

Ordinance Survey website have [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PonDmRJLOA07c8edm6cgizRK5n_JiF1lgZO6cU3YzIA/edit?usp=sharing) where you can supposedly "Perform simple ("Helmert" style) coordinate transformations. E.g. between WGS84 and OSGB36 with an accuracy of about 3 metres." But I can't make heads or tails of it.

There are supposedly some scripts on [this website](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html) that work, but agian I can't understand if any of them will work in google sheets.

There's [a ready-made formula](https://willgeary.github.io/data/2016/11/04/Geocoding-with-Google-Sheets.html) which I can plug into the script editor for converting postcodes into coordinates. I would just like to know if there's something similar for WGS84 Latitude/Longitude to OSGB36 Grid Reference.

Here's [an example google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxIU1v-JSwPSbi8D7SKF3VpUylSV6AWHWZ2kJYANlJk/edit?usp=sharing) anyone can edit.

Comment: Your spreadsheet link is dead/resting so I cannot see the formula in C6.  Please revive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a website that works with no rate limit:

https://gridreferencefinder.com/batchConvert/batchConvert.php

Thanks to the other answer MattKing for your efforts anyways, it's a good answer that can be applied elsewhere. :)

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO! A tip to improve your answer is to include some code snippets showing how you were able to use that website to solve your original question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this website](http://www.nearby.org.uk/conversions.cgi).  And was able to build this formula which you'll find in cell C6, to scrape the answers. I'm not sure how many calls the web server will allow you to make, but it's at least a place to start.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi?p="&SUBSTITUTE(B6,", ","%2C+")&"&f=conv#WGS84%20UTM","/html/body/div/b[4]")
```

Comment: I actually found a website that works with no rate limit, but it was an interesting answer as I hadn't thought to use ImportXML:
https://gridreferencefinder.com/batchConvert/batchConvert.php

Comment: exellent! Hopefuly  people will find that in the future if they stumble across this thread.  Maybe you should put it as an "answer" to your own question?